# Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference on C# String.IsNullorEmpty in VS2019

Tags: c#, string, isnullorempty

I use the String.IsNullorEmpty to check if a cell in Excel worksheet is null or empty. Why VS2019 still reports a error if the cell is empty?
I am sure the worksheet wshIO exists and the intRowIO is 1 when this error came out. The code associated with this worksheet before this line works very well.
[image]

Comment: Note, don't paste images of code or errors. They re hard to read, and cannot be searched by a search engines and indexed. Instead paste that actual code, and the actual exception

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `ToString` on (potentially) a null *dynamic* type.

For instance, it's the same scenario as the following:

```
dynamic s = null;
s.ToString(); // Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference
```

One fix is to use the *null conditional operator*, which will check the *dynamic* type for `null`.

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(s?.ToString());
```

Or related to your example:

```
string.IsNullOrEmpty(something.Cells[x,y].Value2?.ToString())
```

Comment: Thank you, General. You are right. Actually I just need to check if the range is null. I don't need to get the string from the range, which might be Null.  I used something.Cells[x,y]!=Null solved the issue.

Comment: Eventually, I use string.IsNullOrEmpty(something.Cells[x,y].Text) in my code as Cells[x,y]!=Null does not work actually. !=Null cannot detect a blank cell. I don't know why. I guess that's a separated question.